# Calulate two random numbers in flutter

Tags: random, dart, flutter, numbers, calculation

I'm trying to generate two different random numbers and add those together, but Flutter doesn't seem to like my math. I keep getting the message that '+' isn't defined for the class Random.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Random Numbers',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.orange),
      home: MyHome(),
    ));

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var num1 = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      print(num1.nextInt(10));
    }
    var num2 = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      print(num2.nextInt(10));
    }
    //var sum = num1 + num2;

    return Container();
  }
}
```

My goal is to display it something like this: "2 + 5 = "
where the user will fill in the answer. If correct do this else do that.

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that you're trying to add two `Random` objects, and not two numbers. You're printing them correctly, using `nextInt()` on your loops, but when you try to sum them, you're using the original variable of the type `Random`.

Try this:

```
class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // Instantiate a Random class object
    var numGenerator = new Random();

    //You don't need a second loop because it was the same exact code,
    //only with a different variable name.
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      print(numGenerator.nextInt(10));
    }
    // Save the numbers you generated. Each call to nextInt returns a new one
    var num1 = numGenerator.nextInt(10);
    var num2 = numGenerator.nextInt(10);
    var sum = num1 + num2;

    //use num1, num2 and sum as you like    

    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now when I run it I got 10 ints from each num1 and num 2. From the sum I got one answer, which doesn't sum up with num1 and num2.                    I/flutter (17272): num 1
I/flutter (17272): 2
I/flutter (17272): num 2
I/flutter (17272): 3
I/flutter (17272): sum
I/flutter (17272): 12

Comment: I ran it with just one calculation: Num1 =>2; Num2 =>3; sum=>12

Comment: @J.W everytime you call `nextInt` you get a new number. Are you saving those numbers? Maybe we should make the code a bit cleaner, I've edited the answer to make it better. Save the value you generated so you can know later what that number was.

Comment: @J.W If this solved your problem, please mark this answer as correct by clicking the green check under the voting section on my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Gerorge and Sorry for my abscense.

I got some help to solve this through dart

```
Random seed = Random();
const int MAX_VALUE = 10;

int val1 = seed.nextInt(MAX_VALUE);
int val2 = seed.nextInt(MAX_VALUE);
int sum = val1 + val2;

print('$val1 + $val2 = $sum');
```